# transpose the column based on condition in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a test table and records like this:

```
id1    id2   city    state
123    999   GKP      UP
123    999   Bhopal   MP
```

I want my output like this:

```
id1  id2     legal_addr   mailing_addres
123   999     gkp UP       Bhopal MP
```

Please assist me on this.Thanks!

Comment: How do you choose which is legal and which mailing address? Something is wrong with the design.

Comment: how to recognize which record is for `legal_addr` and which for `mailing_addres`? or you have only two record for particular id?

Comment: first record will treat as legal and 2nd one threat as mailing ..if 2nd record not exsit then it means that mailing address similar as legal_address..

Comment: IT IS NOT POSSIBLE HOW CAN IT FIND WHICH ONE MAAILING ADDRESS AND WHICH ONE IS LEGAL ADDRESS

Comment: soory for confussion...if satate is UP then its treat as legal_address and if state is MP then it means that its a mailing address

Comment: Can there be only UP and MP as states??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query to get desired result.

```
with your_table(id1,id2,city,state) as 
(select 123,999,'gkp','UP' from dual union all
select 123,999,'Bhopal','MP' from dual)
------
-- End of data preparation
------
select id1, 
       id2, 
       min(decode(state, 'UP', city ||' '||state, null)) as legal_add, 
       min(decode(state, 'MP', city ||' '||state, null)) as mailing_add
  from your_table
  where state in ('UP', 'MP')
group by id1, id2 ;
```

11g and above can use pivot too

```
with your_table(id1,id2,city,state) as 
(select 123,999,'gkp','UP' from dual union all
select 123,999,'Bhopal','MP' from dual)
------
-- End of data preparation
------
select *
  from your_table
pivot (min(city||' '||state) for state in ('UP' as legal_address, 'MP' as mailing_address)) ;
```

Output:

```
ID1 ID2 LEGAL_ADDRESS   MAILING_ADDRESS
---------------------------------------------
123 999 gkp UP          Bhopal MP
```